# Incorrect backlinks listed in Google Webmaster Tools (Search Console) from my other website

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot, backlinks

I have two websites hosted on the same server (same IP), say `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com`.

Google Webmaster Tools has been set for both the websites years back and everything was fine till the beginning of this year. Upon checking the backlinks for `www.example2.com` in Google Webmaster Tools, thousands of links were listed as backlinks from my other website `www.example1.com`. But not even a single page at `www.example1.com` has a link referred to by `www.example2.com`. I have rechecked it.

I cannot understand why in my Google Webmaster Tools it is like this. SEO is perfect and clean for my sites, Can somebody please provide a solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: These links had to have existed at one point even if not now. It takes a long time for links to drop from the index. You may be looking at 6 months or more.

Comment: Since you control abc.com too, you can ask google to reindex it, which might fix the backlinks issue.